# How to output specific columns separated by a special delimiter using cut

Tags: files, search, printing, cut

I have a file which contains several columns separated by special delimiter with multiple chracters like this: `<xx>`.

A line will look like this:

```
firststring<xx>11<xx>thirdstring/<xx>22<xx>00<xx>00<xx><xx><xx><xx>-1<xx>-1<xx>1
```

Some columns does not contain anything, that's why I have some columns like: `<xx><xx>`

I need to print the 8th and 9th columns of all rows. How to do this? I tried this command but it does not print anything.

```
cat myfile.txt | cut -d '<xx>' -f8,9
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Most* implementations of `awk` allow multi-character field separators. So you can try:

```
awk -F'<xx>' '{print $8,$9}' myfile.txt
```

If you want to preserve the original separators, then you will need to set the *output field separator* `OFS` as well, for example

```
awk -F'<xx>' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $8,$9}' myfile.txt
```

Alternatively, there's [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) if you want a more `cut`-like syntax:

```
mlr --nidx --ifs '<xx>' cut -f 8,9 myfile.txt
```

or, preserving the custom separator

```
mlr --nidx --fs '<xx>' cut -f 8,9 myfile.txt
```

Comment: If I will use the first one, how will it separate them? Can I print them with their original separator <xx>

Comment: @user12591981 please see updated answer